# Number of pairings of smaller to larger numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know if given a list of numbers in asending order there is a way to know the number of smaller to larger pairings without working them out

example,

[1,2,3] has 3 pairings -> [1,2] , [1,3] and [2,3]

For say 1-100 how could one work out the number of pairings ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting an ordered pair $(a,b)$ of numbers in $\{1,2,\cdots,100\}$ where $a<b$ is the same as selecting a set of two numbers in the same set, because once selected there is exactly one way to put the pair into ascending order. So total number of ways is $\binom{100}{2}.$ [The last symbol is the binomial coefficient of $n$ things taken 2 at a time, which means number of sets of size 2 taken from a set of $n$ things. It has the formula $n(n-1)/2,$ where in this problem $n=100.$]